# How to setting listener for button inside the Crouton Toast and clear that Crouton Toast using that button?

Tags: android, crouton

I have an app, which shows toast below the actionbar. I'm using Crouton library for displaying toast. Here I'm placing custom layout for toast, that layout contains one textview and one button (for close option). So Toast appears with button. If I click that it should close the toast but nothing happens.. Below Code for this example. Any Help Appreciated

### MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener {

private View customToastView;
private TextView customToastMessageView;
private Button customToastCloseButton;
private Button doneButton;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    doneButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.done_button);
    customToastView = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.toast_custom_layout, null);
    customToastMessageView = (TextView) customToastView.findViewById(R.id.messages);
    customToastCloseButton = (Button) customToastView.findViewById(R.id.close_button);
    customToastCloseButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    doneButton.setOnClickListener(this);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {

    switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.done_button:
            Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
            customToastMessageView.setText("Message");
            Crouton.show(this, customToastView);
            break;
        case R.id.close_button:
            Crouton.cancelAllCroutons();
            break;
      }
  }
}
```

### toast_custom_layout.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/messages"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="26dp"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/close_button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="23dp"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

### activity_main.xml

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

<Button
    android:id="@+id/done_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="146dp"
    android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: The "crouton" tag is about the Cruton library for Android. Please review the tag wiki.  We do not need two new tags in its place.

Comment: Have you stepped into the onClick method and are sure, that your case `R.id.close_button` is being executed?

Comment: Which version of Crouton are you using? Also: The method `Crouton.hide(Crouton)` is a better way of hiding a single Crouton.

Comment: Crouton.hide(Crouton).. while using this statement its throws an error saying expression expected?